# .png to .h5 file conversion code is running very slow. Please suggest how can I run it in GPU

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, h5py

I am using below code for **conversion of .png images into a single .h5 file**. This code is working fine, but conversion is very slow. I have 40GB data of size 224 x 224 pixels which need to be converted into .h5. Please tell me why my code is running very slow. If I want to run the code in GPU, what are the changes required in my code. Please suggest.

```
import cv2
import datetime as dt
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as plb
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob


start = dt.datetime.now()

PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('/home/sd/Downloads/', 'he'))

SOURCE_IMAGES = os.path.join(PATH, "patch", "training_data")

images = glob(os.path.join(SOURCE_IMAGES, "*.png"))
images.sort()


NUM_IMAGES = len(images)
HEIGHT = 224
WIDTH = 224
CHANNELS = 3
SHAPE = (HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS)
    #Now we will write the h5 file
train_shape = (len(images), HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS)

hf=h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
hf.create_dataset("train_img", shape=train_shape, maxshape=train_shape, compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)

for i, img in enumerate(images):
    s=dt.datetime.now()
    img=cv2.imread(images[i])
    img= cv2.resize(img, (WIDTH,HEIGHT), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    hf["train_img"][i, ...] = img[None]
    e=dt.datetime.now()
hf.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line `hf.create_dataset("train_img", shape=train_shape, maxshape=train_shape, compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)` into `hf.create_dataset("train_img", shape=train_shape, maxshape=train_shape, np.int8)`